# Backbone PUT request explicitly with out using id

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to PUT the data and my model doesn't have an id.

Is it possible to explicitly tell the Save() method to PUT the data irrespective of ID.

Answer (score 0):

The `save` method has an `options` parameter that can override anything on the XHR:

```
model.save(newVals, { type: 'PUT' })
```

You can also override the `isNew` method. `PUT` vs `POST` is determined by the result of that method. You'll also want to make sure the URL is being created correctly for new and non-new objects.

Also consider setting the `idAttribute` correctly so that your model *does* have an `id` field that can be used to generate a correct url.  Using `POST` and `PUT` correctly (`POST` new items, `PUT` updates to items) makes your api more intuitive.

Comment: you might consider accepting the answer, it will help future askers